# PDF.js how to create a page rendered event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, promise, pdf.js

I am using PDF.js with the default viewer and need to detect every time a page is rendered.

This should happen when the document is opended, scrolled or zoomed.

As far as I know I can only use promises when I myself render a page explicitly, but is there a callback or something to listen to whenever a page is rendered? Actually getting the page (as int would be enough) is also very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For explicit rendering:

Well, I checked [the source](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L1299-L1332) and it seems that if you render the page explicitly you can use:

```
page.render(content).promise.then(function(){
  alert("done");
});
```

Which the docs state:

> Promise for rendering task completion.

#### Implicit rendering

Well, you can always override page to provide an event yourself, render is not on any prototype so this gets really ugly. `render` calls return a [`RenderTask`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L1299) which has an [`InternalRenderTask`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L1339) which has a callback. So you can trick it by doing this:

```
var renderTask = page.render(...); // make any page render anything anywhere
var internal = renderTask.__proto__;
var oldNext = internal._next;

internal._next = function(){
     if((this.operatorListIdx === this.operatorList.argsArray.length) &&
         this.operatorList.lastChunk){
         anyPageRendered(this.pageNumber);             
     }
     // decorate
     return oldNext.apply(this, arguments);
};

function anyPageRendered(pageNumber){
    // your code here
    alert("Rendered " + pageNumber); 
}
```

This is undocumented and can break. There is no documented way to do this.

Comment: Small follow up: Shouldn't there also be a may to call my code inside the viewer? The viewer has a pageViewDrawCallback and I've tried to call my code before callback(); to no success. So far calling it at the end of pageviewDraw has worked, but at that point I don't have access to the textLayer div. Which means rendering isn't fully completed yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the lastest viewer (not API), there is also 'pagerendered' event.

Comment: @sollniss like async5 said - in viewer this is a lot simpler - you can use the `pagerendered` event.

Comment: Putting the code into TextLayerBuilder_renderLayer seems to work fine so far.